# How to have a jupyter notebook use the correct kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

On a MacOS Mojave I am trying to run a `jupyter` notebook with a python 3.7 kernel. Following [this instructions](http://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove) I did the following:

```
virtualenv -p pythpn3.7 venv3.7
source venv3.7/bin/activate
pip install jupyter
ipython kernel install --name "venv3.7" --user
```

I then start a notebook

```
jupyter notebook some_notebook.ipynb
```

and I select the kernel `venv3.7`, but when I do a `python -V` I get an answer `python 3.6.9` instead of `python 3.7.6`. And when I do a

```
!which python
```

inside the notebook I get the *wrong* answer

```
/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/bin/python
```

So how to get a python 3.7 kernel inside a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions shown in [this page](http://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove) **are wrong**!
The correct way to do this is:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv3.7
```